# Extract all citations from .tex file

Tags: bibtex

Is there a fool-proof way to extract all bibtex citation-keys that are cited in a `.tex` file?

I do not mean regular-expression magic on the `.tex`-file because this is bound to cause problems when switching between `natbib`, `apacite` etc. which all use different citation commands. Also, citations made using `\nocite{*}` will not be included ...

I though about looking into the `.bbl` file which does contain all references included in the final document but the format of the `.bbl` file differs vastly between packages as well such that the key-extraction is difficult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The citations are contained in the `.aux` file.

```
\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\let\origcitation\citation
\AtEndDocument{\def\mycites{\@gobble}%
  \def\citation#1{\g@addto@macro\mycites{,#1}\origcitation{#1}}}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\typeout{***^^JCited keys: \mycites^^J***}}
\makeatother
```

This will show on screen and in the .log file, at the end of the LaTeX run, a message such as

```
***
Cited keys: xxx,yyy,*
***
```

It would be possible to avoid the appearance of `*`, but I don't think it's worthy the trouble. Only actually cited keys will appear (BibTeX uses `\citation{*}` as a signal for including the whole database).

One can output the citations to an auxiliary file, instead:

```
\makeatletter
\let\origcitation\citation
\AtEndDocument{\def\mycites{}%
  \def\citation#1{\g@addto@macro\mycites{#1^^J}\origcitation{#1}}}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\newwrite\citeout\immediate\openout\citeout=\jobname.cit
  \immediate\write\citeout{\mycites}\immediate\closeout\citeout}
\makeatother
```

Then, if the file is `test.tex`, the citation keys will be saved in the file `test.cit` one per line.

Comment: Yes, I noted that \nocite{*} citations do not appear. However, in the .aux file, all items appear in \bibcite{} commands (at least in my current test-setup)...

Comment: `\bibcite` entries are written when reading the `thebibliography` environment, so also keys coming from `\nocite{*}` will be there. The right entries are the `\citation` ones.

Comment: so, replacing \citation with \bibcite everywhere in your code will output all the used citation keys? That would be exactly what I need...

Comment: I tested it and it works. One minor issue: latex breaks the output at (probably) exactly 80 characters such that the list is broken at weird places. Since I want to use the output in a script, is there a way to output it without line-breaks?

Comment: @thias Yes, it's possible, see edited answer

Comment: In unix-like systems, one can write `cat myfile.aux | grep "\\\\citation" | sed 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' | sort | uniq > myfile.cit` and the resulting file contains all used citations, and each of them exactly once.

Comment: @tohecz: Good approach. However, to be fool-proof you additionally have to replace `,` by newlines in the sed output to get one key per line – the `\citation` argument may be a comma-separated list of keys.

Comment: @Daniel This one should be safer: `cat myfile.aux | grep "\\\\citation" | sed -e 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' -e 's/,/\n/g' -e 's/ *\(.*\) */\1/g' | sort | uniq > myfile.cit`. How does it work: `grep` selects the correct lines, `sed` 1st extracts the parameter, 2nd splits the commas, 3rd trims the whitespace, `sort` and `uniq` are self-explanatory.

Comment: @tohecz: Not really, apparently it is not so easy to insert a newline with sed. However, the following works: `cat paper.aux | grep "\\\\citation" | sed -e 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' -e 's/ *\(.*\) */\1/g' | tr ',' '\012' | sort -u`

Comment: @Daniel well, I tested it and it worked :-/ can you post the line from `.aux` that caused you the troubles?

Comment: @Daniel btw, my LaTeX puts in the `.aux` file `\citation{a}<newline>\citation{b}` for `\cite{a,b}` in the code, hence it seems the whole thing with comma is unnecessary

Comment: @tohecz I can confirm that my `sed` doesn't allow `\n` in the substitution string. There are many variations of `sed` around. When you use `natbib`, arguments to `\citation` can have the comma.

Comment: @tohecz: I guess this depends on the bibliography style. If you use `\bibliographystyle{acm}`, for instance, `\cite{a,b,c}` is transformed into `\citation{a,b,c}`. So substitution of commas to newlines seems to be more robust.

Comment: @egreg: What is the `biblatex` way of doing this? Is it possible?

Comment: @Dror I believe so, but it's probably better to open a new question.

Answer (score 11):

With [`bibtool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool) you can do as follows:

```
bibtool -- preserve.key.case=on -x file.aux -o bibliography.bib
```

This extracts your cited bibliography. Now if you just `grep` the file for lines with `@` in them, you get fairly close to a list of keys. The option `preserve.key.case=on` ensures that the case of the keys is not altered (in response to the comment below).

Comment: nice! However, I want to get along without bibtool. I found that it destroys some of my entries. For example, it decapitalizes my keys all the time...

Comment: See also bibexport [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41823/28411]

Answer (score 3):

Various TeX-aware programming editors have macros to achieve this. For instance, there's a package called `bibmacros` for use with winedt which (inter alia) does the job you describe. It works on the .aux file created by latex and BibTeX, and creates a new bib file called jobname-minimal.bib, where *jobbame* is the name of the aux file (without the "aux" extension, of course). Other editors must have similar macros, either built-in or accessible as extra packages.

Comment: Hey, that's right! For emacs, I found M-x reftex-create-bibtex-file...

Comment: @thias --- Really?  I don't see that option in reftex 4.31.  Could you elaborate?  (I usually use bibtool, but it doesn't handle cross-references in the .bib file very well, so an emacs solution would be great.)

Comment: Found in menu [Ref] -> [Global Actions] -> [Create BibTeX File]