# Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file

Tags: bibtex

Normally, LaTeX will only create references for the BibTeX entries cited in the text. Is there a way of extracting these entries into a different `.bib` file automatically? For example if I have a `.bib` file with two entries, and only one is cited in a particular text, I need a way of creating a new `.bib` file with just that reference.

Comment: For Mac users of BibDesk, there is [BBL to BIB with BibDesk](http://jevopi.blogspot.com/2010/04/bbl-to-bib-with-bibdesk.html).

Comment: For Windows, JabRef provides this capacity: see [here][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98370/how-to-generate-a-bib-file-with-citations-in-a-texmaker-project

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417/how-to-split-all-bibtex-referenced-entries-from-a-big-bibtex-database-to-a-copy

Comment: BBL to BIB seems cool but does not seem to be compatible with biber/biblatex.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in overleaf somehow?

Comment: @canIchangethis: yes. by creating a custom `latexmkrc` along the lines of `$lualatex = 'lualatex %O %S; bash ./export.sh';`, where you can put whatever shell commands you like in `export.sh`.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. Your code in an otherwise empty latexmkrc does generate my PDF but does not generate the selective bibfile - at least don't know where I would find it in my overleaf. Any suggestion how I can use a shorter bib export tool in a biblatex, pdflatex, and biber workflow in overleaf?

Comment: @canIchangethis: did you add one of the other answers below to the contents of `export.sh`? If so, the generated file should appear in the other outputs within the log pane of overleaf.

Comment: wait, export.sh is also a file? How do I create this?

Answer (score 154):

With a TeX Live distribution (possibly also with MiKTeX) there is a `bibexport` program. Assuming your document is `myarticle.tex`, you have to compile it normally and then you call

```
bibexport -o extracted.bib myarticle.aux
```

where `extracted.bib` is the name that you want to give to your new `.bib` file. 
Notice that you have to give the extension `.aux` (or no extension at all).

Then you have to change the name of the `.bib` file in your document, in order to use `extracted.bib`.

Comment: In MiKTeX 2.9 this tool is missing :-(

Comment: Although this falls outside of the scope of the question, perhaps a brief word about how this tool does not work with `biber`-driven bibliographies (or with `.bib` files that use `biblatex` fields such as `date` instead of `year`) is in order.

Comment: @jon `bibexport` uses BibTeX for doing its job. The manual tells how to add new fields (section 1.4). For `biblatex`/Biber compatibility the script should look not only for `\citation` commands in the `aux` file but also for `\abx@aux@cite`.

Comment: @egreg -- Right.  I was thinking more for people who look at your answer, but don't realize why `bibexport` isn't working for them; most of them are not going to be modifying `bibexport.sh`.  Another problem that might arise is if you use non-standard entry types (from BibTeX's perspective).  I use `@Collectio{<key>,...`, e.g., for essay collections; that comes through as `@{<key>,...`.

Comment: +1 for the usage example – the `bibexport` help page doesn't mention that the main argument is the *.aux* file (it might be obvious, but wasn't for me).

Answer (score 61):

`jabref` can do this in both command line and gui modes.

First gui mode:

Keep your `master.bib` file open in jabref. Then in `Tools` → `New subdatase based on AUX file` to get

[image: screenshot of AUX file import dialog box]

Here select the `.aux` file, click `parse`, and `select` and the `generate`. You should get a sub database opened in jabref. Save it.

From command line, assuming that you take care of paths do this:

```
jabref.jar -a filename[.aux],newBibFile[.bib]
```

See also [command line options to jabref](https://docs.jabref.org/advanced/commandline).

Comment: In contrast to the `bibexport`-solution above, this one works when working with `biblatex` and `biber`.

Answer (score 43):

This is a supplement to [pavel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171394/39222) which aims to address an issue raised in the comments. It is therefore a more specific solution than the one there: the simpler command will work fine if you don't need to resolve `crossref` fields in `.bib` entries.

In order to resolve `crossref` fields in a `.bib` file when using `biblatex`/`biber`, you need to tell `biber` what to do.

Given `<filename>.tex`, run:

```
pdflatex <filename>.tex
biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve <filename>.bcf
```

Where `latex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` etc. can be substituted for `pdflatex` as appropriate. So long as it generates your `.bcf` it is fine.

Answer (score 31):

With `biblatex`/`biber` you can use

```
biber document-base-name.bcf --output_format=bibtex
```

To resolve `crossref` fields, add the option `--output-resolve-crossrefs`.

Comment: The above command doesn't work with entries using the `crossref` field.

Comment: @asr See my answer below. You just need to tell `biber` to do this.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to egreg's answer, I'd like to point out an alternative solution. Nelson Beebe has developed utilities called `bibextract`, `citetags` and `citefind` to handle sub-bibliography databases. You can obtain them [here](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub//bibextract/).

In this case, you would compile the document normally and then type in a shell

```
citetags myarticle.aux > myarticle-tags
citefind myarticle-tags mybib.bib > mysubbib.bib
```

The first command prints all the citation keys used in your `.tex`, while the second selects all the entries from `my bib.bib` with keys from `myarticle-tags`. Of course, one can easily write a script to merge the two commands if needed.

Although it works in a similar fashion as `bibexport`, this solution has the advantage that it does not delete the `biblatex` fields such as `date`, while `bibexport` does by default as mentioned in the comments. It also works with `biblatex` if you use `bibtex` as a backend, but as far as I know, it does not if you use `biber`.

Answer (score 8):

I thought I'd chime in since this came up for me when searching, and none of the given answers worked for me.

As comments allude to, the `bibexport` program doesn't seem to be included in some LaTeX distributions anymore (it's certainly not in the texlive version I'm using).

I also tried the `citetags`/`citefind` commands described by @Corentin but they produced an empty file as output. I don't use `biber` or OSX either, so the other answers didn't help.

I then found that `bibtool` can do this, as follows:

```
bibtool -x article.aux -o NewBib.bib
```

It also turns out that this answer has already been given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136839/89790

Answer (score 4):

I manage to do it with JabRef 4.3.1 using the command line only. It works in Windows 10 as well. The answer provided by @user11232 is out of date. The right command is:

```
jabref.jar -n -a old_ref.aux,new_ref.bib old_ref.bib
```

`-n` means we do not use the GUI and the output will be in `new_ref.bib`.

You can find `jabref.jar` on the [new website](https://www.jabref.org/) of JabRef. The documentation for the command-line usage is also updated in a [new place](https://docs.jabref.org/advanced/commandline).

Comment: Of all the solutions presented in this thread, this is the only one that reliably extracts all used references from my bibliography into a small bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take the cited references from the .bbl file and remove references from the .bib file not listed in .bbl with this Python script:

```python
bib_file = 'large_bib_file_to_clean.bib'
bbl_file = 'corresponding_bbl_file.bbl'

def get_cited_entries(bbl_file):
    with open(bbl_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        bbl_content = f.read()
        
    bibitem_matches = re.findall(r'\\bibitem.*{([^}]*)}', bbl_content)
    return set(bibitem_matches)

def remove_unused_entries(bib_file, cited_entries):
    with open(bib_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        bib_content = f.read()

    # Split .bib content into entries
    bib_entries = re.split(r'(@\w+{)', bib_content)
    new_bib_content = ''

    # Iterate through entries and keep only cited ones
    for i in range(1, len(bib_entries), 2):
        entry_type = bib_entries[i].strip()
        entry = bib_entries[i + 1].strip()
        key_match = re.match(r'^([^,]*)', entry)
        if key_match:
            key = key_match.group(1).strip()
            if key in cited_entries:
                new_bib_content += entry_type + entry + '\n\n'

    # Write to .bib file
    with open(dir+'updated.bib', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(new_bib_content)

cited_entries = get_cited_entries(bbl_file)
remove_unused_entries(bib_file, cited_entries)
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0):

Corentin's solution worked for my case where I needed to combine cited references from multiple .tex documents into one bib file. I had trouble installing `bibextract` on OSX for two reasons: 1) nawk is not installed by default and 2) the CHECKSUM command in the makefile prevented the sh and awk files from being installed. After running, `./configure`, modifify the Makefile as follows:

change:

```
SEDCMD          = $(SED) -e 's=@LIBDIR@=$(LIBDIR)=g' \
                     -e 's=@BINDIR@=$(BINDIR)=g' \
                     -e 's=/bin/sed=$(SED)=g'
```

to

```
SEDCMD          = $(SED) -e 's=@LIBDIR@=$(LIBDIR)=g' \
                     -e 's=@BINDIR@=$(BINDIR)=g' \
                     -e 's=/bin/sed=$(SED)=g' \
                     -e 's=nawk -f=awk -f=g'
```

then change

```
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.sh | $(CHECKSUM) > $(BINDIR)/$$f ; \
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.awk | $(CHECKSUM) > $(LIBDIR)/$$f.awk ; \
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.man | $(CHECKSUM) > $(MANDIR)/$$f.$(MANEXT) ; \
```

to

```
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.sh > $(BINDIR)/$$f ; \
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.awk > $(LIBDIR)/$$f.awk ; \
        $(SEDCMD) $$f.man > $(MANDIR)/$$f.$(MANEXT) ; \
```

then run `sudo make install` and `bibextract` will work as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [WinEdt](https://www.winedt.com/) as the front end to your TeX distribution, I suggest you download and install the [bibMacros package](https://www.winedt.org/macros/latex/bibMacros.html) (if you haven't already done so). Upon installation, you will see a new ribbon item, labelled "BibTeX". In the tex file that generated the bibliography, click on the "BibTeX" ribbon item to open a drop-down list of further items, and then on the "Extract from Aux" item. These actions let you create a new bib file that contains just the items that are cited in the document.

Answer (score -1):

Complete steps to use "bibexport" for 'extracting  only the cited references of a bigger .bib file'. Need Unix environment.

1. Download the bibexport from [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibexport). The important files are 'bibexport.dtx' and 'bibexport.ins'.
2. In the terminal build the '.ins' file using latex. command: latex bibexport.ins. I am assuming that the 'latex' package is already installed in your system.
3. This will generate a bunch of files named 'bibexport.sh', 'expcites.bst', 'expkeys.bst', 'export.bst' and log file.
4. Copy all three '.bst' files and 'bibexport.sh' to the folder where you are writing the article in latex. Also, change the permission of the 'bibexport.sh' file to executable e.g, 'chmod 755 bibexport.sh'.
5. If you have already compiled(successfully) your article, 'MyArticle.tex', in latex then you should have a file in '.aux' extension. If not, then compile your 'MyArticle.tex' file first using 'latex MyArticle.tex' and 'bibtex MyArticle.aux'. Do this a few times until the compilation finishes without any errors or warnings.
6. Now it's time to extract the "cited" only references from the "big" bibliography file say 'BibliographyAll.bib'. Use the command " ./bibexport.sh -o ./BibliographyForThisPaper.bib ./MyArticle.aux" in the terminal.
7. A file named 'BibliographyThisPaper.bib' will be generated which contains only the references that has been used in the article.

   You can use this file in your main latex file. \bibliography{./BibliographyForThisPaper}. For other options and usages follow the manual of bibexport which also comes with the package, just you have to build it. Do "pdflatex ./bibexport.dtx"

Comment: Before installing by hand, check if the package is available prebuilt for your TeX distribution (or as a package for your system).