# How to generate a .bib file with citations in a TeXmaker project?

Tags: bibtex, miktex, jabref

I am relatively new to LaTeX, so please bear with me, just started using it for my thesis.

I am using JabRef to manage my citations and TeXmaker as the editor. I really don't know the workflow people normally use to manage their citations, but the way I am doing it is: I have a `.bib` I manage with JabRef in which I have all the papers relevant to my thesis, however, I am not citing them all.

**What I would like to know is if there is some kind of way (maybe a plugin), I can use to automatically export the citations I am using in my TeXmaker project in JabRef**. I used to be able to do this with EndNote. It would have a filter for which references I am using in the MS Word Document.

Hope to have made it clear.

P.S. Using TeXmaker is not a requirement for me. So, if the solution consists of using another editor, that won't be a problem.

Comment: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41823/25792) might be of interest if you want to make a new .bib file only containing the cited entrys from a big database.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file (courtesy to Storm). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: it is exactly the same. however, I am using MiKTex, and the bibexport tool is not available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In JabRef, go to **Tools --> New Subdatabase based on AUX file**, choose the `.bib` and `.aux` file belonging to your project. This will read the citation keys from the aux file, and extract the corresponding entries from the bib-file.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. you're my savior!

Comment: Awesome, thank you!