# Extracting only the BibTex records relevant to the paper

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, collaboration

My colleague asked me to write a page for a paper he writes. I wrote the page in LyX, compiled it to LaTeX, and sent him the TeX files. Then he reminded me that I forgot to send the .bib file with all the references.

But, my .bib file is huge - it contains over 1000 references (I have a global BiBTeX file for all my papers). The page I wrote uses only about 20 of them.

Is there an automatic way to extract from the bib file, only the records relevant to the current paper?

Comment: You could send him the .bbl file (provided that you haven't used the `\nocite{*}` command, or else you'll get ALL your bibliography file).

Comment: JabRef can for example create a new .bib-file based on a `.aux` file, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98370/how-to-generate-a-bib-file-with-citations-in-a-texmaker-project/98396#98396 See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file

Comment: @MarioS.E. I don't see any bbl file;

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't see any .aux file... I only have .bib and .tex .

Comment: Ah, sorry (on two counts). The `.aux` file is generated when you run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` file. Also, do you use `biblatex` as the tag suggests? In that case you probably have to add `backend=bibtex` as an option to the `biblatex` package before you compile.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did: "pdflatex myfile.tex" "bibtool -x myfile.aux > myfile.bib"

Comment: I am not sure about bibtex/biblatex. I just used LyX's "export to LaTeX" command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution would be to use [bibtool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool). It only works with BibTeX though, not Biblatex.

Use the following command to extract relevant entries:

```
bibtool -x myfile.aux > myfile.bib
```

Comment: I see that it can extract entries from an aux file, but I don't have any aux file... LyX export creates only .tex .

Comment: Presumably you can just run e.g. [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) on your .tex file and that will generate an .aux file.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did: "pdflatex myfile.tex" "bibtool -x myfile.aux > myfile.bib". Probably I have BibTeX and not Biblatex (I used LyX export so I don't know).

Comment: To ensure that the keys are not converted to lowercase, I use: echo "preserve.key.case=on" > /tmp/b; bibtool -r /tmp/b -x myfile.aux > myfile.bib

Answer (score 22):

If you want to give a `bib` file away only including entrys which are cited in a document use package [bibexport](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibexport).  If you have a main TeX file `mwe.tex` and want to create a short `bib` file `short.bib` use:

```
bibexport.sh -o short.bib mwe.aux
```

You get an resulting bib file `short.bib` containing only cited/crossreferenced entrys from your main `bib` file.

Comment: I found it easier to use than bibtool, since it does not convert the keys to lowercase by default.

Answer (score 7):

Through the compilation a file `.bbl` is created. There are the relevant references of your manuscript.

You could insert the content of this file directly on the `.tex` in the place of the bibliography (erasing the command `\bibliography{....bib}` of your original text).

Comment: +1. This is far and away the simplest solution, especially if you just use `\input{foo.bbl}`.