# Get TeX to output a minimal .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

Is there a way I can get LaTeX to output a .bib file containing only the citations actually in my document? I often copy and past over old .bib files, which makes them rather unweildy over time. Is there any way to get tex to run, and then instead of giving me a pdf, it gives me a new .bib with only the citations actually used in the document I've run it on?

Comment: Please see my answer in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136837/extracting-only-the-bibtex-records-relevant-to-the-paper/136865#136865. Possible duplicate?

Comment: See `bibtool` for BibTeX and `biber` for, well, Biber.