# Which natbib file should I save in an archive

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, archiving

I work with a very large `bibtex` file when I write articles. The `bib` file is in version control and is collaboratively edited by a large group of scholars with similar interests. This creates a 'moving target', which means that if I go back to compile an article that was written years ago, some of its references may have been changed, so the result does not equal the original, as it would have compiled then. At the same time, creating multiple copies of this very large `bib` file would be very inefficient.

One solution is to simply save a pdf of the compiled document in version control (I do this currently, and will continue to do this). Additionally, I also wondered if it is not possible to just add the `bbl` file to version control. That way you don't need to access any `bib` file to compile the document as it was. Is this a valid approach? Any drawbacks? Other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to a utility program that extracts just the cited entries from the bib file and can create a new bib file? That way, even if the full bib file is potentially very large, the one that's used for the final (or near-final) version of the paper needn't be particularly large.

Comment: @Mico I don't know which utilities do that. That would be an excellent solution.

Comment: You can extract the cited records with `bibexport`

Comment: Please see my answer in question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136837/extracting-only-the-bibtex-records-relevant-to-the-paper/136865#136865

Comment: Which front-end editing software do  you use? If it happens to be WinEdt, you could install and make use of the excellent [bibMacros](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/BibTeX.php) add-in package. One of the add-ins makes it trivially easy to create a new bib file that contains just the entries cited in your tex document.