# How to project a bibtex file to the references used in a LaTeX article?

Tags: bibtex

Some conferences require for the final version a bibtex file containing ONLY the references referred to in the article. Whereas it can be done by hand, it sounds like a task that could easily be automatized. Before programming something on my own, I tried to check if such a program existed already, without success. I am checking here on stack exchange before starting to program it.

More formally, such a program would

- receive as input

  - a LaTeX document $D$ and
  - a bibtex database $B$; to
- produce

  - a bibtex database $B'$ which contains only the bibtex entries referred to in the LaTeX document.

A simplification would be for $B'$ to contain only the bibtex entries which key is present in the bbl file generated when compiling the LaTeX document.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?  On unix like platforms `bibtool` works well.   See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417/15925

Comment: Please see my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136837/extracting-only-the-bibtex-records-relevant-to-the-paper/136865#136865

Comment: If you use the WinEdt software suite, you could download the `BibMacros` macro package from winedt.org; one of the tools of this macro package lets you extract just the cited entries from a bib file and write them to a new bib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/ is the answer.

The way to use it is as follows:

- latex file.tex # to generate an aux file
- bibtool -x file.aux -o refs.bib  # to project the bibliography into refs.bib