# Can I programmatically typeset .bib file data with Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, documentation

In working on improved documentation for a Biblatex style, I'd like to print nicely styled verbatim .bib entries beside the output for each, thereby juxtaposing cause and effect. This could be done by hand for each entry, but I hoped it might be easier to define a custom Biblatex citation command for typesetting .bib entries exactly as they appear in the file. A custom citation command would not only save tedium, but it would also help with automating documentation.

Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to access the literal data in a field, if this is even possible. I'd imagine Biber's already processing and parsing the data before Biblatex even sees it, and my use case is probably complicated by wanting to juxtapose unprocessed .bib data with stylized, processed Biblatex output. Here's a simplified version of what I have so far, along with the output for two entries:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{documentation.bib}
@article{Tibullus:2002ub,
    author = {Tibullus},
    date = {2002/2003},
    journal = {Chicago Review},
    number = {4},
    pages = {102--106},
    title = {How to Be Tibullus},
    translator = {Wray, David},
    volume = {48}}

@article{Evacuation:wj,
    date = {2016-07-15},
    entrysubtype = {newspaper},
    journal = {The Boston Globe},
    title = {Evacuation Order Lifted at Nice Airport},
    url = {www.bostonglobe.com/news/world/2016/07/15/evacuation-progress-nice-airport/KO4BytWK4wFUOxjEkSpKTN/story.html}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{documentation.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\samplebib}[\texttt]
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\newline}%
   \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace{}and\addspace{}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:mla:bib}}
  {}%
  {}

\newcommand{\entrycolor}{\color{teal}}
\newcommand{\fieldcolor}[1]{{\color{purple}#1}}
\newcommand{\fieldindent}{{\color{white} ~~~}}

\newcommand{\fieldcite}[1]{
  \iffieldundef{#1}%
    {}%
    {\printtext{\fieldindent\fieldcolor{#1} = \{\printfield[noformat]{#1}\}}}%
  \ifnameundef{#1}%
    {}%
    {\printtext{\fieldindent\fieldcolor{#1} = \{\printnames[family-given][-\value{listtotal}]{#1}\}}}%
  \iflistundef{#1}%
    {}%
    {\printtext{\fieldindent\fieldcolor{#1} = \{\printlist{#1}\}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:mla:bib}{%
  {\entrycolor\printtext{@}\printfield{entrytype}}\{\printfield{entrykey}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{author}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{date}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{day}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{entrysubtype}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{institution}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{journaltitle}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{journal}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{month}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{number}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{options}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{pages}%
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{title}
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{translator}
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{url}
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{volume}
  \newunit%
  \fieldcite{year}%
  \newline%
  \}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\noindent\samplebib{Tibullus:2002ub}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\noindent\samplebib{Evacuation:wj}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of bibtex documentation]

The output shows that the `date` entry is now gone, replaced by `year`, `month`, and `day` as needed, without any range. Likewise the `journal` field is converted with `journaltitle`--though this kind of conversion is less of a problem. Other entries will have similar substitutions, too, but they boil down to the same problem. (I understand why this is the default and have no complaints!) Is it possible to insist that Biblatex should show the literal .bib input for every field, or are these values out of reach? Perhaps more importantly, have I overlooked a better way to programmatically typeset Bibtex data from an existing .bib file for documentation?

Comment: I've been working on this for awhile now and had my hopes raised this morning when I saw this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601342/how-can-i-programatically-write-a-biblatex-file-containing-all-and-only-the-ref (Unfortunately, we weren't after the same goal.)

Comment: why don't you simply input the bib (or a part by line number or with some markers) with the listings package?

Comment: The listing package was one of the first ways I tried. As I understood it, it still required the (tedious) reproduction of .bib entries each time I wanted to show an entry's metadata. While my example above has been minimized to show only two citations, my documentation, when finished, will probably print a couple hundred sources, recreating examples from a handbook.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean with "reproduction".

Comment: It may be that I misunderstand the capabilities of the listings package. If I have ~200 entries in an external .bib file, will the listings package allow me to call up the data from one of them by, e.g., the cite key? I *think* the package requires me either to copy and paste each entry ("reproducing" it) into my .tex file or to reference the specific line numbers I'd like to show—but these will shift when a bib file has changes and additions. (Or can I programmatically indicate these line numbers?)

Comment: you could use line range markers, see 5.7 Arbitrary linerange markers in the listings docu.

Comment: Ah! This looks viable. I can pre-process the .bib file to name line range markers with cite keys, which should make it easy to  drop listings in programmatically. I'll give it a try in the next day. Thank you for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: For my `biblatex-ext` documentation I use `\newtcbinputlisting` with line numbers, but of course that requires manual adjustments when the `.bib` file changes. You could avoid this by using `.dtx` files to create the duplicate data (`for .bib` file and `.tex` file) from a single source without duplication. See for example the documentation of `biblatex-oxref`: https://github.com/alex-ball/biblatex-oxref/blob/master/oxref.dtx

Comment: It is very tricky to reconstruct the `.bib` data on the LaTeX side because  you'd have to undo all of Biber's pre-processing steps (most prominently date parsing, but also field aliasing [`journal` -> `journaltitle`] and much more for `crossref` etc.) That might be possible for simple examples, but becomes less and less viable the more advanced features of `biblatex` you want to use.

Comment: In my last comment I should have probably made clearer that once on the LaTeX side of things you absolutely cannot distinguish whether input used `journal` or `journaltitle` (that is the point of the sourcemapping by Biber). Of course Biber would have the info available, but it's not exposed to the LaTeX side of things. For most simple dates it should be possible to reconstruct the `date` value, but it would get fairly messy for complex dates.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you! If you'd like to make it an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @moewe thank you for pointing me to some other good options. Your documentation in biblatex-ext is very user friendly! And what you say about the options left available by Biber's sourcemapping makes good sense to me. The tradeoff of losing literal specificity is very much worth it to gain an easier data workflow with Biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconstructing the bib-file from the bbl is not really possible as biber does a number of preprocessing you can't revert on the LaTeX side.

So I would use the listings package to include the bib-file verbatim.

A part of the file can be selected either by line numbers or --- if the line numbers are not stable enough --- you can use range markers as described in the listings documentation, 5.7 Arbitrary linerange markers.

Comment: Thank you! This worked well. I pre-process my bib files in R (because it's what I know), and then use the listings package to include that data in my Latex documentation. Here's a gist to my R code to prepare a bibfile: https://gist.github.com/jmclawson/882c7ff79e5e9fdf37973a38ca52571a Here's the gist to Latex code for creating a \bibcitem command for use in documentation: https://gist.github.com/jmclawson/6b04d45ca5f5e05d021586b4da508760

Answer (score 1):

Instead of preprocessing the files yourself you can also use [Bibtool](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/bibtool.pdf), which allows to extract single entries from a `.bib` file (among many other things).

You can call Bibtool from within LaTeX using `\write18` to save an entry to a temporary file and then use `\lstinputlisting` on that file. Note that this requires compiling with `-shell-escape`.

Bibtool does some processing on the file, such as adding a newline at the startof the file, and converting cite keys to lower case. You can switch that off.

MWE, based on your gist:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{BibTeX}{%
  % keywordsprefix={@}%
  keywords={%
    @book,@article,@incollection,@suppbook,@mvbook,@collection,@review,@misc,%
    @thesis,@mvreference,@inreference,@mvlexicon,@inlexicon,@unpublished,%
    @commentary,@inbook,@incommentary,@mvcommentary,@seminarpaper,@lexicon,%
    @reference,@mvcollection,@bookinbook,@ancienttext,@classictext,@online,%
    @manual,@conferencepaper,@series%
  },
  emph={%
    author,title,location,publisher,date,shorttitle,translator,edition,preface,%
    related,relatedtype,editor,series,shortseries,number,journal,journaltitle,%
    shortjournal,volume,pages,type,booktitle,bookauthor,origlocation,%
    origpublisher,origdate,pubstate,origlanguage,maintitle,maineditor,part,%
    bookeditor,seriesseries,maintranslator,eprint,eprinttype,doi,url,%
    revdauthor,revdtitle,revdeditor,institution,type,shorthand,xref,%
    note,eprintdate,volumes,shortmaintitle,options,eprintclass,relatedoptions,%
    editortype,crossref,editora,editorb,editorc,editoratype,editorbtyle,%
    editorctype,entrysubtype,sorttitle,titleaddon,witheditor,witheditortype,%
    withtranslator,withtranslatortype,eventtitle,venue,eventdate,shortauthor%
  },
  sensitive=false,
  breaklines=true,
  %breakatwhitespace=true,
  morecomment=[l][basicstyle]{=\ \{}
}

\lstset{%
 language=BibTeX,
 backgroundcolor=\color{gray!5},
 basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
 keywordstyle=\color{teal},
 emphstyle=\color{purple}
}

\lstset{rangeprefix=\%\[\[\ ,% percent + double left square brace + space 
        rangesuffix=\ \]\]}% space + double right square bracket 
        
\addbibresource{documentation.bib}

\newcommand{\sidebyside}[1]{%
\begin{refsection}%
\nocite{#1}%
\immediate\write18{bibtool -- suppress.initial.newline=true -- preserve.key.case=on -X "^#1$" documentation.bib -o tmpsingle.bib}%
\lstinputlisting{tmpsingle.bib}%
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
}

\begin{document}
\sidebyside{Tibullus:2002ub}

\sidebyside{Evacuation:wj}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: tested on Linux only, I'm not sure the command line call will work as given on Windows or Mac - but if it doesn't then probably it can be adjusted easily.

Comment: I'd seen Bibtool mentioned in some other answers to other questions, but I wasn't aware it was able to do the kinds of things you show here. This looks like a great addition to the workflow. Thank you for suggesting it!