# Automatic extraction of cited references to a bib file

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have a very long `bib` file, and instead of using it as is, I'd like to have a short `bib` file with only the cited references for my paper. That is, I'd like to automatize extracting cited references from an `aux` file and create a `bib` file.

I found out that `bibexport.sh` has such capabilities, but it does not work for me as it does not find the `\abx@aux@cite{}` entries.

So my question is how to edit `bibexport.sh` to search for `\abx@aux@cite{}` entries?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601345/2388