# bib file from a bbl file and source bib

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, bbl

This has possibly been asked before, but I couldn't find any answer.

Some editors would like to have the bib file corresponding to the paper (so they process the bbl to their liking).

For personal reasons, I prefer not to disclose all of my (rather large) source bib file(s) but would like to send only those items that are used in the specific bbl file corresponding to the manuscript.  But in bib format, not bbl format.

Before I start writing my own perl script, I was wondering if there was some utility that already exists out there that does the job.  Processes a bbl file and outputs all the bib records cited therein.

This is for vanilla bibtex, but I'm happy to use biblatex and biber.

Comment: with biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601345/2388.

Comment: with bibtex: [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/5001)