# Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file in Windows

Tags: bibtex, miktex, windows

Mine is closely related to this one: [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file)

I ask the same question but with a solution for Windows. The mentioned solutions `bibexport`, and `bibextract` don't seem to be available. I think it's possible to run these programs through something like MinGW, but I'd like to be able to have something that works on the command line so that I can build it into my usual build command.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `biblatex`/`biber` is an option, you can use `biber` to generate a document-specific `.bib` file. All you need is a document using `biblatex` compiled to generate the usual `.bcf` which `biblatex`/`biber` uses. Then you can run:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve <filename>.bcf
```

where `<filename>` is the name of your `<filename>.tex`.

Comment: I do prefer biblatex/biber, but it is not supported in the Elsevier `elsarticle` template yet.

Comment: @kennyB You could use it to produce the `.bib` file, though, couldn't you? You don't need to then use it for the article itself.

Comment: I think `bibtex` only produces an `.aux` file, whereas `biber` produces a `.bcf`? Right?

Comment: @kennyB Yes. But you can use the `.bcf` to create a `.bib` file. Then run TeX again with BibTeX setup and use the custom `.bib` file. The `.bcf` is just needed to create the `.bib` file. That is, I'm not sure what point you are making/asking about?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - when using the elsarticle template, I'm restricted to using natbib with bibtex as it's built in to the .cls file somehow. So, when I generate the document, there's no `.bcf` to use the above command with. Is there an `aux` to `bcf` tool out there? Thanks!

Comment: @kennyB Oh, I see what you mean now. Sorry - I'm not familiar with the template and thought it was just specified in the template for the document rather than the class. And I am afraid I don't know if there is such a converter.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind installing `jabref`, it can do it for you. Both command line ([link here](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CommandLine.php)) and gui options are available. From command line do

```
jabref.jar -a filename[.aux],newBibFile[.bib]
```

You should be done. Take care that `jabref.jar` is in system path, and run this command from the same folder as your `.aux` file.

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar, I have tried this solution with the following command:
`<aux file location>>JabRef-2.10.jar -a bellEtAl.aux,bellEtAlCited.bib`
The behavior is simply to open the JabRef Gui and nothing else happens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much

Comment: I have managed to get this to work through the GUI as well. So at least a have a partial solution.

Comment: @kennyB Can you try `jabref -a bellEtAl.aux bellEtAlCited.bib source.bib` where `source.bib` is your master bib file?

Comment: I first delete `bellEtAlCited.bib`, then run the above command. When I try this, the behavior is again to open the JabRef GUI with `source.bib` open and the error message `Error opening file bellEtAlCited.bib. null`.

Comment: @kennyB It looks like a bug :(