# How to create bib file from only keys, not AUX file, with JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, lyx

These questions ask [how to create a small .bib file with the references used in a paper from a larger one in general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file) and [in Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212124/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file-in).

Here, I ask how to export the references from JabRef, if you only have the BibTex keys, not an AUX file.

(In my case, I extracted the keys from a non-compiling LyX file...)

Answer (score 3):

I followed [Harish Kumar's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212133/23423), but I needed to make a fake Aux file.  To do this, I used a text editor to insert `\citation{ }` around each of my bibtex keys, e.g.

```
\citation{johnson1998selective}
\citation{peterson1478eulerian}
\citation{anderson2014questionable}
```

I pasted all of these into an ".aux" file, and pointed JabRef at that.