# Checkcites package not working properly

Tags: biblatex

I have compiled the .tex document, and the auxiliary file is in the same directory as my .bib file, and I am running the script from this directory.

I am using BibLaTeX for my references, and I cite by using the \parencite{} and \textcite{} commands - does it matter that I don't use the \cite{} command? Also, I have my report sections in separate .tex files, but I don't think this should matter as I get no section-specific .aux files from compiling.

When I run `$ checkcites main.aux`, I get the following output:

```
checkcites.lua -- a reference checker script (v1.0i)
Copyright (c) 2012 Enrico Gregorio, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda

I found 0 citation(s).
I couldn't find any bibliography files.
I'm afraid I have nothing to do now.
```

Comment: You can do something similar with `biblatex` and Biber directly. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: A solution that works within the document and not via the command line is [How to split bibliography into “works cited” and “works not cited”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864). There is also [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212134/35864). And unknown references are already listed in the `.log`: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sigfridsson' on page 1 undefined on input line 27.`

Answer (score 4):

`checkcites` is not intended to be used with `biblatex`.

*(I just asked the developers in chat, see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37760751#37760751)*

Comment: That's too bad.