# Automated Way To Generate Standalone .bib File?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, export

I have a latex document which has several citations. These citations are from my global `.bib` file that I manage with JabRef. The `documentclass` of my document is `IEEEtran` (I doubt my use of `IEEEtran` affects the answer, but this is my usecase, so I figured I would ask in context).

I am getting ready to share my document (and the `.tex` file) and would like to share a minimal working `.bib` file with it. My question is: is there an automated way of extracting the entries from a `.bib` file using the `.tex` or `.aux` files of a document so that the output `.bib` only contains the bibtex entries cited by the document?

Obviously, I could manually go through my document, find the keys, copy the relevant entries from my global `.bib` file to one called `standlone.bib` or some such. But I'm curious if there are any extant automated ways. Or if there are not any automated ways, are there any simple commands to get there?

I have been searching and was unable to find any answers to this question, so please forgive me if this is a duplicate as I did not know what terms to search for beyond "latex standalone bib from tex", etc.

For completeness, suppose I have a document such as the below MWE snippet in a file called `document.tex`.

```
% document.tex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

% ... Various preamble commands

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Sed mattis pellentesque mauris. Sed non nisi ut velit 
ullamcorper congue non eu erat. Aliquam pharetra nibh
magna, eu consectetur risus aliquet vel. Aenean eget
turpis dui. \cite{key1}

Sed in tristique nibh, vel ultricies lorem. Pellentesque
sem lacus, maximus ac laoreet eu, mattis at sem. Maecenas
dignissim sagittis nisl, non interdum nunc auctor nec.
Proin ac ipsum quis lorem placerat accumsan sed quis sem. \cite{key2}

% ...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{jabrefBib}

\end{document}
```

Example of the command I hope exists:

```
$ exportbibfromdoc --stand-alone-bib document.tex -o standalone.bib
```

so that the output would be

```
% standalone.bib
@ARTICLE{key1,
...
}

@BOOK{key2,
...
}

...
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864

Comment: That's it! Feel free to close this question. Turns out my search-fu was lacking...