# How to create a .bib file with only citations of a current article (out of the main .bib file containing 100-200+ citations)?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm writing an article and have to communicate the references in a .bib format with my co-authors. I have a single central .bib file (where there are 100-200+ citations) but want to give the .bib file containing only the (approx) 20 citations cited in the article. Is there a command/manoeuver/shorcut to generate such a file? I use vim as a text editor and use terminal for commands (such as pdflatex as well as `biber` for citation management. I looked at [this question](http://pple.stackexchange.com/): and ran sequentially:

```
pdflatex filename
bibexport filename
```

I got the following message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
The top-level auxiliary file: bibexp.1620677239.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibexp.1620677239.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibexp.1620677239.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibexp.1620677239.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

as well as a empty file `bibexport.bib`

I then tried the following command:

```
$ biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve report.bcf
```

but got the following output:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'report.blg'
INFO - Reading 'report.bcf'
INFO - Found 28 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '/Users/path/to/biblio.bib'
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/Users/path/to/biblio.bib'
WARN - month field 'aug' in entry 'Baumgartner_2017' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'jun' in entry 'Nishimura_2014' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'jan' in entry 'Baumgartner_2009' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'dec' in entry 'Baumgartner_2016' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'oct' in entry 'O_Sullivan_2013' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'aug' in entry 'Nishimura_2002' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'jun' in entry 'Fougeres_2012' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'apr' in entry 'Boulain_2002' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'dec' in entry 'Clavel_2013' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'apr' in entry 'Clavel_2010' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'sep' in entry 'Rao_2018' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
WARN - month field 'jan' in entry 'Ha_2018' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/BNmPZUubEF/biblio.bib_16500.utf8, line 29, syntax error: found ":", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
INFO - WARNINGS: 12
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Here ar the first 47 lines of the biblio.bib file:

```
@article{Howell_2015,
    doi = {10.1530/erp-15-0005},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1530%2Ferp-15-0005},
    year = 2015,
    month = {mar},
    publisher = {Bioscientifica},
    volume = {2},
    number = {1},
    pages = {R37--R44},
    author = {Neil Howell and William Bradlow},
    title = {Surgical management of left ventricular outflow obstruction in hypertrophic cardiomyopathy},
    journal = {Echo Research and Practice}
}



@article{Chahal_2015,
    doi = {10.1016/j.jcmg.2015.04.021},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.jcmg.2015.04.021},
    year = 2015,
    month = {oct},
    publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
    volume = {8},
    number = {10},
    pages = {1133--1139},
    author = {Navtej S. Chahal and Maria Drakopoulou and Ana M. Gonzalez-Gonzalez and Ramasamy Manivarmane and Rajdeep Khattar and Roxy Senior},
    title = {Resting Aortic Valve Area at Normal Transaortic Flow Rate Reflects True Valve Area in Suspected Low-Gradient Severe Aortic Stenosis},
    journal = {JACC: Cardiovascular Imaging}: Cardiovascular Imaging}
}



@article{Caballero_2017,
    doi = {10.1016/j.echo.2016.10.006},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.echo.2016.10.006},
    year = 2017,
    month = {jan},
    publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
    volume = {30},
    number = {1},
    pages = {28--35},
    author = {Luis Caballero and Daniel Saura and Mar{\'{\i}}a Jos{\'{e}} Oliva-Sandoval and Josefa Gonz{\'{a}}lez-Carrillo and Mar{\'{\i}}a Dolores Espinosa and Miguel Garc{\'{\i}}a-Navarro and Mariano Vald{\'{e}}s and Patrizio Lancellotti and Gonzalo de la Morena},
    title = {Three-Dimensional Morphology of the Left Ventricular Outflow Tract: Impact on Grading Aortic Stenosis Severity},
    journal = {Journal of the American Society of Echocardiography}
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` as the tag suggests, then `bibexport` might not work. You may want to try the Biber-based suggestions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864

Comment: Indeed you are write @moewe. I'm actually using biber. Still looking for the answer in your link

Comment: You have to scroll down a wee bit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212134/35864

Comment: Yes I scrolled then a bit but got the following error message (in the edited question)

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines (at least up to l. 30) of `biblio.bib`? Biber reports an error. Apparently there is a `:` that shouldn't be there. (You should also check your `month` fields, `month = {apr},` is wrong and should be `month = apr,` because months are technically implemented as `@string`s and not as normal field content.)

Comment: Many thans for your feedbacks @moewe. I added the 3 first citation of the biblio.bib file (47 first lines)

Comment: Yeah, there is a typo in `Chahal_2015`: In `journal = {JACC: Cardiovascular Imaging}: Cardiovascular Imaging}` the curly braces don't match. It probably should just be `journal = {JACC: Cardiovascular Imaging},`

Comment: @moewe YOU ROCK!!!! Many many thanks. If you want and / or care, I'll be delighted to accept your answer if you write one

Comment: I think the main part of the question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864. The colon was just an unrelated typo (which probably does not warrant a complete answer, since it would distract from the main point). So I'd be inclined to vote to close as a duplicate if that is alright with you.

Comment: @moewe. Yes of course. Many thanks again