# How to export references from a bbl file to csv?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bbl

I have a `.bib` file, but not all references are cited.

I want to list all cited (only) references in a `.csv` file.

But, the `.bib` file contains references that are not cited as well.

What I understood is, the `.bbl` file contains the cited references only.

So, how do I export the cited references to a `.CSV` file?

Comment: It might be easiest to use some other programming language to go through the two files.  But in that case, I'm not sure it would be on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you are using `biblatex` or BibTeX, the `.bbl` file might not really lend itself to being read back by a machine if you want to recover all data. If you only want to recover which entries were cited and no additional data, that is less relevant.

The `.bbl` file produced for BibTeX bibliographies contains typesettable text and thus requires quite intricate parsing if you want to get back the entry data.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Elk(1972)]{elk}
Anne Elk.
\newblock \emph{A Theory on Brontosauruses}.
\newblock Monthy \& Co., 1972.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Since the style decides what gets written to the `.bbl` file, some data might be missing.

The `.bbl` file produced for `biblatex` contains entry data in a structured, LaTeX-readable format that could in theory be parsed to get back all entry data.

```
\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nyt/global//global/global}
    \entry{elk}{book}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{un=0,uniquepart=base,hash=6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}{%
           family={Elk},
           familyi={E\bibinitperiod},
           given={Anne},
           giveni={A\bibinitperiod},
           givenun=0}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {London}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Monthy \& Co.}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \strng{fullhash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \strng{bibnamehash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \strng{authorbibnamehash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \strng{authornamehash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{6a9b0705c275273262103333472cc656}
      \field{sortinit}{E}
      \field{sortinithash}{8da8a182d344d5b9047633dfc0cc9131}
      \field{extradatescope}{labelyear}
      \field{labeldatesource}{year}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{title}{A Theory on Brontosauruses}
      \field{year}{1972}
    \endentry
  \enddatalist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

The `.bbl` file generated for `biblatex` will contain context-specific data that is only relevant within the current document context. This may or may not be wanted when you want to export the data to `.csv`.

But I would go down a different route. I would use one of the methods from [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864) to generate a `.bib` file of only the cited references and would then use a library to read in the `.bib` file directly.

Comment: Thanks. The method suggested using JabRef worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a complete list of citations in your document from the `.aux` file. Each `\cite` command will cause an entry to be written in the `.aux` file in the format

```
\citation{REFNAME}
```

where `REFNAME` is the name you used in the `\cite` command. It will create a separate `\citation` command for each reference in a multi-reference `\cite` command, so if you, for example, typed `\cite{foo,bar}` in your document you will see

```
\citation{foo}
\citation{bar}
```

From here, you can do what you want to generate your CSV file, so if you're on a Unixish system (including MacOS and Linux), you can write

```
grep '\\citation` my.aux | sort | uniq
```

that will give you a list of all the reference names cited in your document with duplicates removed.