# Creating bib file containing all items cited in two (!) book projects

Tags: biber

I am already using this to extract all items cited in a book:
[Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file) But now I want to extract all cited items from two books.

So up to now I used:

```
 biber --output_format=bibtex --output-legacy-date handbook.bcf -O hpsg-handbook-bibliography.bib
```

Now I would like something like:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex --output-legacy-date handbook.bcf gt.bcf -O new-bibliography.bib
```

So the idea is to pass two .bcf files. Is there a trick to make this work? Alternatively the only way to get the items is to create a document including all the tex stuff from both projects. But this would be 2500 pages and probably a code nightmare.

Comment: create two bib-file with the entries from each book. Copy them all in one large bib-file, and then run `biber --tool large.bib`, biber will then create a large_bibertool.bib and remove all duplicates in the process.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Very simple! Sorry for asking.