# How can I see the number of bibliographic references that are present and used in two LaTeX projects?

Tags: bibliographies

I have two LaTeX projects: [LaTeX project 1](https://arxiv.org/src/2309.00770), [LaTeX project 2](https://arxiv.org/src/2312.01509). How can I see the number of bibliographic references that are present and used in both LaTeX projects?

Comment: Questions shouldn't depend on external links. Nor should they demand people parse whole projects. Please provide a minimal working example that illustrates your problem. Then people will be happy to help. Do they both use the same bibliography backend? Which?

Comment: @cfr thanks, I found a generic solution that works on any project size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can count the number of bibliographic references that are present and used in two LaTeX projects as follows:

1. Take project 1, [remove](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714142/11400) ([script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714330/11400)) all unused entries in the .bib file: let's call that cleaned file `project1.bib`. Do the same bib cleaning operation for project 2, which yields `project2.bib`.
2. [Merge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714218/11400) `project1.bib` with `project2.bib`.
3. Count the number of unsolved references when compiling project 1 with the new merged .bib file.