# How can I remove all unused entries in a .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies

I have a [very large .bib file](https://aclanthology.org/anthology+abstracts.bib.gz), which I use in my latex project (a research paper).  How can I remove all unused entries in a .bib file?

I don't want to only list them (as `checkcites` does), but instead I want to remove them. I found https://github.com/jamestrimble/remove-unused-citations but its readme mentions it's unreliable.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/105447 solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

[bibtool](https://github.com/ge-ne/bibtool) can do it.

First build your document. Then, run

```
bibtool -x <jobname>.aux -o <outputfile>.bib
```

The tool assumes you don't just want to clobber the original database, so it extracts the entries used from your giant database and saves it into a new database that you specify. You are of course free to then move the original database elsewhere and rename the new one to match the old.

(Note, since `bibtool` is reading the `aux` file, it can tell where the original database is, so you needn't specify that on the command line.)

Comment: +1 You can do the same with GUI in JabRef (menu Tools). For a individual reference there also a tab to see if that reference is cited elsewhere, so it is also easy mark it manually  in some way (e.g., use the score column, add a  keyword, use some code in bibkeys, etc.) to allow to sort/search and select references by that mark.