# How can I merge new.bib with old.bib so that new.bib uses entry names from old.bib, for the entries present in both new.bib and old.bib?

Tags: bibliographies, merge

I have a LaTeX project (a research paper) that uses .bib file (`old.bib`). I received a new .bib file (`new.bib`), which includes the BibTeX entries present in `old.bib` with more complete information, but sometimes using a different [entry name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp4Bi.png).

How can I merge `new.bib` with `old.bib` so that `new.bib` uses entry names from `old.bib`, for the entries present in both `new.bib` and `old.bib`? Note that I don't want to add any entries in `new.bib`, but only change entry names for entries also present in `old.bib`.

---

Example (in practice I'll have much longer .bib files):

Input:
`new.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{lesterpaper,
  title={The Power of Scale for Parameter-Efficient Prompt Tuning},
  author={Lester, Brian and Al-Rfou, Rami and Constant, Noah},
  booktitle={Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing},
  pages={3045--3059},
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  year={2021}
}

@article{bommasani2023holistic,
  title={Holistic Evaluation of Language Models},
  author={Bommasani, Rishi and Liang, Percy and Lee, Tony},
  journal={Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

`old.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{lester,
  title={The Power of Scale for Parameter-Efficient Prompt Tuning},
  author={Lester, Brian and Al-Rfou, Rami and Constant, Noah},
  booktitle={EMNLP},
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  year={2021}
}

@inproceedings{tokpo2022text,
  title={Text Style Transfer for Bias Mitigation using Masked Language Modeling},
  author={Tokpo, Ewoenam Kwaku and Calders, Toon},
  booktitle={NAACL: HLT-SRW},
  pages={163--171},
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  year={2022}
}
```

Output new `new.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{lester,
  title={The Power of Scale for Parameter-Efficient Prompt Tuning},
  author={Lester, Brian and Al-Rfou, Rami and Constant, Noah},
  booktitle={Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing},
  pages={3045--3059},
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  year={2021}
}

@article{bommasani2023holistic,
  title={Holistic Evaluation of Language Models},
  author={Bommasani, Rishi and Liang, Percy and Lee, Tony},
  journal={Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

The only change in that new `new.bib` in the example is that the Bibtex entry name `lesterpaper` was changed to `lester`.

Comment: I don't see how any automated tool could be expected to do this reliably. `lester` and `lesterpaper` are not the same entry as `booktitle` differs. What is to distinguish a case where the same authors have published under the same title in two different books issued by the same publisher in the same year versus a case where you've entered different titles for the same book in different places? If you had a unique identifier, I could see how it might work - at least in principle - but that would need something like ISBN for books.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, let's assume the title is enough to merge.

Comment: Maybe look at scripting `biber` in tool mode? Not sure if you could do it just with `biber` or if you'd need something else. Thinking about it, if your bib files are reasonably consistently formatted, you could probably just use `awk`. You could even just `cut` `old.bib` and `new.bib` into pieces, pull `title` from each piece of `new`, `grep` `old` and get the key if there's a match. Then just sed/awk to replace the key. Of course, it probably wouldn't work on Windows, but it seems doable anywhere else.

Comment: As @cfr, I see no completely automated way to do this (at least, if you expect it to be "safe"). But I don't see why some kind of interactive tool could not assist with the task. I'm not a JabRef user myself, but I recall it having some features of the sort. See, for example: https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/findduplicates, https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/mergeentries.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks,  "edit distance algorithm. Extra weighting is put on the fields author, editor, title. and journal." is pretty much exactly how I would code it.

Comment: @gusbrs I wondered about that, but I don't know JabRef well enough to make any suggestion. So it may come down to how consistent the formatting is and how much work is involved in GUI-assisted versus scripting. Does JabRef overwrite keys, though? I seem to remember that being a problem with many GUI `bib` managers, but I've not looked at any for years.

Comment: @cfr As I've said, I'm also not a JabRef user, so I'm not well acquainted with the process. But I'd expect it to interactively identify potential duplicates and let the user decide what to keep, overwriting if necessary, of course. So I think it is a supervised process rather than an automatic one. It only helps find the duplicates, which is better than trying to "eyeball" them, and guides one through conflict resolution. Well, that's what I'd expect, I've never actually used it. ;-) Anyway, for this particular task, for the reasons you mentioned, I'd go with a GUI rather than a script.

Answer (score 1):

Reddit user [CommanderCoo](https://www.reddit.com/user/CommanderCoo) [wrote](https://redd.it/1bpjdec) this Python script based on the Python library [BibTexParser](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/main/) to merge the two Bibtex files based on title, authors and year:

```python
import bibtexparser

#Define bibtex files
old_bib = "old.bib"
new_bib = "new.bib"

#Open bibtex files
with open(old_bib) as bibtex_file:
    old_bib_database = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)
old_entries = {entry['ID']: entry for entry in old_bib_database.entries}

with open(new_bib) as bibtex_file:
    new_bib_database = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)
new_entries = {entry['ID']: entry for entry in new_bib_database.entries}

#Compare bibtex files
for new_id, new_entry in new_entries.items():
    for old_id, old_entry in old_entries.items():
        #Parameters for bibtex entry comparison
        if old_entry.get('title') == new_entry.get('title') and \
           old_entry.get('author') == new_entry.get('author') and \
           old_entry.get('year') == new_entry.get('year'):
            new_entries[new_id]['ID'] = old_id

#Aggregate merged bibtex information
new_bib_database.entries = list(new_entries.values())

#Throw the bibtex into a new file
with open('merged.bib', 'w') as bibtex_file:
    bibtexparser.dump(new_bib_database, bibtex_file)
```

That works.