# Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries were not used?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites)

While reading papers, I put those that I'd like to refer to or mention in customized `.bib` files (one `.bib` file for each paper). (Thanks to [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) it's pretty easy and straight forward - they call it "collections").

My intention is that all entries in the `.bib` file should be mentioned in the text.

How to check which bibliography entries I have not referred to ?

Comment: If tex code would be helpfull here, or more details, please let me know, I'd love to improve question.

Comment: Only those entries `\cite`d will appear in the bibliography. If you want to make a `.bib` file that consists of only those entries cited, then see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32032/extract-all-citations-from-tex-file

Comment: If you are in a unix-like environment, I can write for you a short script that does exactly what you need. The information on **used** references is stored in the `.aux` file in the form `\citation{ref-label}`.

Comment: Maybe you could extract the cited references from your `.bib` file using [`bibexport`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bibtex-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bibtex-fil) to a new file and then `diff` both to see the differences.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Another way is to use the `refcheck` package and add `\nocite{*}` in your document. This package will warn you (amongst other things) about unused references. My MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo:2012a,
  title = {My Title One},
  publisher = {My Publisher One},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor One},
  author = {Author One}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012b,
  title = {My Title Two},
  publisher = {My Publisher Two},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Two},
  author = {Author Two}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012c,
  title = {My Title Three},
  publisher = {My Publisher Three},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Three},
  author = {Author Three}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{foo:2012a,foo:2012b}.

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: My output]

The reference keys not cited in your document will be displayed between `?...?`. Besides, `refcheck` adds the following line to your `.log` file:

```
<Info by RefCheck> Unused bibitem `foo:2012c' on page 1.
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

**Update:** Based on this question, [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) and I came up with a Lua script called [`checkcites`](https://github.com/cereda/checkcites). The idea of this script is to detect unused or undefined references from LaTeX auxiliary (`.aux`) or bibliography (`.bib`) files.

Consider the following example: `document.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo:2012a,
  title = {My Title One},
  publisher = {My Publisher One},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor One},
  author = {Author One}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012b,
  title = {My Title Two},
  publisher = {My Publisher Two},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Two},
  author = {Author Two}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012c,
  title = {My Title Three},
  publisher = {My Publisher Three},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Three},
  author = {Author Three}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012d,
  title = {My Title Four},
  publisher = {My Publisher Four},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Four},
  author = {Author Four}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{foo:2012a,foo:2012c},
how are you \cite{foo:2012e}, and
goodbye \cite{foo:2012d,foo:2012a}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

After compiling it, an auxiliary file `document.aux` will be generated. Now we will use `texlua` (which is available in both MiKTeX and TeX Live distros) to run `checkcites` on the `.aux` file:

```
$ texlua checkcites.lua document.aux
```

The script will look for all unused and undefined references. The output will be:

[image: checkcites terminal]

If you want to look only for unused references in your `.bib` file, you can add the `--unused` flag:

```
$ texlua checkcites.lua --unused document.aux
```

The argument order doesn't matter, so you can also call:

```
$ texlua checkcites.lua document.aux --unused
```

Similarly, using

```
$ texlua checkcites.lua --undefined foo.aux
```

will make the script only look for undefined references in your `.tex` file.

To look for both unused and undefined references, you can also use the `--all` flag. If no flag is provided, `checkcites` will behave as if `--all` was provided.

The script is now available [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites) and `tlmgr` will install it on TeX Live 2011 (or later). Hope you guys like our humble script. `:)`

**Update:** As `checkcites` is now available on CTAN and TeX Live, there's no need of explicitly calling `texlua` nor the original `checkcites.lua` file; a simple call to

```
$ checkcites --unused document.aux
```

will suffice, since the script is properly wrapped. `:)`

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of this package before. Pretty elegant!

Comment: Very nice package. I was wondering, is it possible to extend the package so that it creates an output file? for example, a latex file that cites the uncited entries. Or at least a simple text file with the list of unused entries that the user can later exploit to generate the report. It can be useful when you are collaborating and you want to send a PDF with this information to your coworkers. Thank you!

Comment: I just tested it with my `Thesis.tex` which is divided in several `.tex` files (I use `\included` to input each chapter). Sadly, checkcites does not work in this case. A citation in `Chap1.tex` is logged in `Chap1.aux`, so there is no record of it in `Thesis.aux`. I naively tried to run `checkcites` to `Chap1.aux`, but it does not have `\bibdata` with the the name of the `.bib`, so it won't be able to find the bibliography to compare with. Any ideas? Anyway, it is still a great package.

Comment: Hi @Felipe! `:)` Thanks for the feedback. Currently, `checkcites` can handle multiple `.bib` files, but AFAIK only one `.aux` file. I'll take a look at the code and try to work on an improved version. `:)` About the output to an external file, a workaround for now would be to redirect the output with `$ checkcites mydoc.aux > out.txt`. Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: That is a good solution for the moment. Although, I encourage you to add the functionality of creating a PDF output. It would be much more elegant! I would do it myself, but I don't know LUA and I am writing my thesis, I don't have much time. Thank you!!

Comment: on the MWE for refcheck solution, I get a File 'refcheck.sty' not found. I get the same error when trying to use it in my larger document. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SwimBikeRun: Sounds like you have an outdated TeX distro. If you have a vanilla install of TeX Live (the one provided by TUG), you need to run ` tlmgr` in order to update your distro (for both Linux and Windows). Now, if you have TeX provided by your Linux distro, you'll need to rely on the available packages in the software manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, etc). Take a look at [this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/updating-tex-on-linux) it might help. `:)`

Comment: I have a thesis.tex file using biber/biblatex, pointing to only one .bib file in a subdirectory, with thesis.aux file in the same directory as thesis.tex. yet i am getting an error "I found 0 citation(s).
I couldn't find any bibliography files.
I'm afraid I have nothing to do now.".   Can someone point out lines of enquiry I can follow to resolve this please?

Comment: @DGarside: I believe `checkcites` doesn't support files in other directory levels, that is, both `.aux` and `.bib` have to be at the same level. A possible solution would be copying the `.aux` file to the same directory of the `.bib` file; I know it doesn't sound like a good solution at all, but it's what I can think of at the moment. `:)`

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer a bit, as it seems from [Know which entry of bib file has not been used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224406) that calling `texlua` explicitly is not necessary.

Comment: @PauloCereda I cannot get the checkcites to work. Does it require that I use the \cite command in my .tex document? I am using \parencite{} and \textcite{}. Also, the checkcites script is says it does not find any bibliography file, but there .bib file is right there in the directory from which I run the script.

Comment: @Yoda: it's been a while, so pardon if I do not remember how my code works. `:)` If I recall correctly, the script inspects the `.aux` file and looks for `\bibcite`.  Regarding the `.bib` file, I might need more info, if possible. Cheers!

Comment: This is a great tool! As far as I understand, `checkcites` is currently not able to handle multiple `.aux` files (which occur e.g. when using `\include`). Are you planning on adding this feature?

Comment: @jpmath: Hi, thanks for the kind words! You are right, `checkcites` does not support multiple `.aux` files at the moment, but we are indeed planning to support this feature! Also, the script is not `biblatex` compliant, so we want to make it compatible too! I am in a hurry because of my thesis, but I will try to do my best and update the tool as soon as possible. `:)`

Comment: Those are great news (also making it `biblatex` compliant). All the best for your thesis!

Comment: I have a project split into several `*.tex` (`*.aux`) files, and I was going to use a for loop in the shell as a workaround for the fact `checkcites` only works with one file at a time. However, I always get the `I couldn't find any bibliography files.` message, likely because the bibliography is only included (directly referenced) in the `main.tex` file, but not in the other files. I am leaving this comment here because other uses will probably also bump into the same issue.

Comment: @jpmath: new version updated, support for multiple `.aux` files was included, as well as `biblatex` support. Cheers!

Comment: @thiagowfx: I added support for multiple `.aux` files, hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: For biblatex users, use the new --backend option, .e.g. `checkcites  --backend biber document`. No need to provide a file extension!

Comment: @ApolloLV: Oh my, I forgot to update my own answer! Will do that ASAP. Thanks for reminding me of this!

Comment: For me `checkcites $(find . -type f -name '*.aux')` worked pretty well!

Answer (score 23):

This question deserves a brief answer to demonstrate how simple [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites) actually is. At your prompt simply type ...

```
$ checkcites my_document.aux
```

... and it prints out a nicely formatted list of unused + undefined references.

This works out-of-the-box if you have a full installation of a recent TeX-Live distribution (2011+), where the command `checkcites` should already by on your path. It's a simple command line tool; no modification in your document is required (e.g. `usepackage`).

I hope my answer will prevent others to manually download the script from CTAN, study the docs, just to find out that RTFM is overkill in this case :).

Answer (score 17):

One possibility would be the following:

1. Switch the bibtex bibliography style to `unsrt` (with biblatex pass the `sorting=none` option)
2. Compile your document --> PDF with cited references
3. At the very end of your document (before the `\bibliography` command) add a `\nocite{*}`
4. Compile your document --> PDF with all references
5. Compare the bibliography of both PDFs. The "extra" entries at the end are those you have not yet cited.

However, if you work in a UNIX-like environment, I would probably use tools like grep and sed to extract the keys from the .aux file and the .bib file and diff them:

```
cat paper.aux | grep '\\citation' | sed -e 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' -e 's/ *\(.*\) */\1/g' | tr ',' '\012' | sort -u > paper.keys
cat paper.bib | grep "@.*{.*," | sed -e 's/.*{\(.*\),/\1/' | sort -u > bib.keys
grep -v -f paper.keys bib.keys
```

The first line extracts all keys given in `\citation{key1[,key2 ...]}` commands from the aux-file into distinct lines, sorts and unifies them (every entry is contained once once) and redirects the result into the file `paper.keys`. 
The second line does the same for the keys contained in `@<some type>{key,` lines in the bib file. The third line  prints out every line from `bib.keys` that is not contained in `paper.keys`, which is the delta you are interested in.

Comment: Why the four backslashes in the argument to `grep`? And wouldn't it be simpler starting with `grep '\\citation' paper.aux`?

Comment: @egreg I think that Daniel took it from me ;) and these things are just a matter of habit I think ;)

Comment: @tohecz Well, on my system it doesn't work with four backslashes.

Comment: @egreg: tohecz an me discussed how to build this line in another question, he is right that I took the grep part from him. The point is: If you put the parameter in double quotes, the shell will substitute them down to two backslashes and grep down to one. If you put it in single quotes (which you probably tried) the shell will not perform substitution, so four backslashes are passed to grep, hence the pattern does not match. I have modified the solution to use single quotes.

Comment: @egreg: I prefer `cat <file> | grep <expression>` just because it is then more visible which `<file>` I am working on (especially if `<expression>` is nontrivial). This is slightly slower, though.

Comment: @Daniel No, I didn't use single quotes: apparently it's `tcsh` that doesn't reduce ``\\`` to one backslash inside double quotes. So if you want that the one-liner runs on as much shells as possible, single quotes seem the best choice.

Comment: +1. In the middle line, `all.keys` should be `bib.keys`, since that's what you use in the last `grep`.

Comment: +1 Because in contrast to the script mentioned above this one works perfect for multiple .aux files.

Answer (score 11):

Given that you are using bibtex and not biblatex, the [Bibtool](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool) utility may be able to help you. Say you have a `myreferences.bib` file you've created in Mendeley or wherever. You write `paper.tex` with the intention of explicitly citing every item from `myreferences.bib`. To see if you've forgotten anything, use bibtool to extract a bibliography of all and only the references cited in `paper.tex` and compare its contents to the original:

```
bibtool -x paper.aux -o paperrefs.bib
```

Now you can compare `paperrefs.bib` to `myreferences.bib`:

```
diff myreferences.bib paperrefs.bib
```

Ideally you'll find there's no difference. You could probably work this up into a script of the sort mentioned by tohecz, but using bibtool means you don't have to come up with a regular expression to catch the various forms of citation. Your original `myreferences.bib` should be sorted alphabetically for this to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/344) will give you a clue, but only for biblatex, I believe. (I won't duplicate it here)

It allows you to use `\nocite{*}` to place all the unreferenced `.bib` file entries in a separate section of the bibliography.

Normally, one might publish this as 'additional reading', for example, but in your case you can use it to help prune your `.bib` file.

Comment: This works only with `biblatex`. I don't think that the OP uses `biblatex` ... P.S. I guess you mean `\nocite{*}` instead of `\nocite(*)`

Answer (score 5):

Under unix-like systems, you can make a following bash script, called e.g. `diffrefs`:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=${1%.???}
cat $f.aux | grep "\\\\citation" | sed -e 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' -e 's/,/\n/g' -e 's/ *\(.*\) */\1/g' | sort | uniq > $f.cit
# cat $f.aux | grep "\\\\citation" | sed -e 's/\\citation{\(.*\)}/\1/g' -e 's/ *\(.*\) */\1/g' | sort | uniq > $f.cit
cat $f.bib | grep "^@" | sed 's/.*{\|,.*//g' | sort >$f.bit
echo "Unused but defined references:"
diff $f.cit $f.bit | grep "^>"
echo "Undefined but used references:"
diff $f.cit $f.bit | grep "^<"
```

**Usage:**
`diffrefs myfile`

**Explanation:**

- `cat $f.aux ...`: outputs the auxiliary file (`cat`), takes the information on used citations (`grep`), extracts the labels, removes white-space (`sed`), sorts and removes duplicates (`sort`, `uniq`)
- `cat $f.bib ...`: outputs the bibtex file (`cat`), takes the first line of each entry (`grep`) removes evertything before `{` and after `,` (`sed`), and does `sort`, `uniq` as before.
- `diff ...`: prints differences between two files, the characters `<` and `>` say "which file is larger by that line"

**Edit:**
I found that LaTeX automatically perorms the comma-seperation of `\cite{...}` parameter, so I removed it from the script.

**Edit:**
In 2021 the code of the previous version works with `elsarticle` (restored with the other version commented `#`)
The script requires the same name for the `.tex` and `.bib` files (in case use `ln -s mybib.bib LaTeXFileName.bib`).

Comment: No, the argument to `\citation` *can* contain commas, depending on the package used for citation, for instance `natbib`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I ran into some issues with the `refcheck` package, a rather simple option would be to load `hyperref` with the `pagebackref` option. Then, doing a `\nocite{*}` in the main TeX file, the bibliography gets back references to the pages where an entry was cited. No citation -> no back reference.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo:2012a,
  title = {My Title One},
  publisher = {My Publisher One},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor One},
  author = {Author One}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012b,
  title = {My Title Two},
  publisher = {My Publisher Two},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Two},
  author = {Author Two}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012c,
  title = {My Title Three},
  publisher = {My Publisher Three},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Three},
  author = {Author Three}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{foo:2012a,foo:2012b}.

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```