# Determining which references have not been cited

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries where not used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/unused-bibliography-entries-how-to-check-which-entries-where-not-used)

I have a very large `references.bib`. Throughout my document, I have used `\cite{}` to cite many of them. Now I would like to know if I missed any - that is, if there is a references in the `.bib` file that has not been called using `\cite{}`. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems like refcheck with \nocite{*} does exactly what I was looking for! Should I make this an "answer" instead of a "comment"? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`backref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/backref), part of the `hyperref` package. It will add links in the bibliography to the pages where the entries are cited. That way you can easily find references you did not use.

```
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Carsten - but hyperref/bibtex does not add the citations at all to the "References" section if they are not referenced. It seems backref adds links from the ones that *are* referenced to the position from which they are referenced. See what I mean?

Comment: @David Yes - you have to look for those entries that have no backref-links.

Comment: But if they have not been cited they are not included in the references list. Where else do you "look" for them?