# Show uncited references using biblatex and refcheck

Tags: biblatex, refcheck

#### Does `refcheck` work with `biblatex`?

If not: **how do I print all uncited references using `biblatex`**?

---

Using the MWE from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/unused-bibliography-entries-how-to-check-which-entries-were-not-used), I can display all the uncited references.
When I try to do the same using `biblatex`, `refcheck` doesn't appear to work. I don't see any error messages when I compile, though. This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\bibliography{refs}
\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{foo2012a}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which is producing:

[image: No <code>refcheck</code> annotations]

I am (hopefully) expecting to see:

[image: what I want to see]

How can I make `refcheck` work with `biblatex` **or** how can I achieve the same thing in a different way (display all references that are not cited in my document)?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use the other answer given in the question you link, i.e. print unsorted bibliography, then add `\nocite{*}` and print bibliography again and compare. Might be easier and faster than trying to solve this problem.

Comment: `refcheck` won't work with `biblatex`, but you could adapt [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/21591).