# refcheck and biber -- warnings on uncited entries

Tags: biblatex, biber, refcheck

\refcheck does not work with biber apparently, as in the following example. Does anyone have a work-around? What do you guys use instead?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo:2012a,
  title = {My Title One},
  publisher = {My Publisher One},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor One},
  author = {Author One}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012b,
  title = {My Title Two},
  publisher = {My Publisher Two},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Two},
  author = {Author Two}
}

@BOOK{foo:2012c,
  title = {My Title Three},
  publisher = {My Publisher Three},
  year = {2012},
  editor = {My Editor Three},
  author = {Author Three}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,backref=true,doi=true,url=false,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{foo:2012a,foo:2012b}.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106673/27635

Comment: I have used the suggestion at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977. Works great for what I want!

Comment: Good. So we can close this one as a duplicate.