# Finding unresolved references

Tags: cross-referencing

How do I find unresolved references? Does LaTeX tell me this somewhere? Is it in a log file? The LaTeX output just says I have unresolved references, but it doesn't tell me what they are, or does it? thanks

Comment: Have you seen my answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128405/references-used-in-article/132150#132150 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. If you compile the following document that contains an unlabelled reference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

your `.log` will contain (amongst other things):

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `abc' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.
```

It will also end (almost as a summary) with:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

notifying you that something is amiss. You also know where these are by searching for `??` in your document - the default definition given to undefined (or unresolved) references - as can be seen by the definition of `\ref` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@secondoftwo{#1}}
```

<sub>Of course, you need to compile at least twice to make there actually is undefined references.</sub>

Comment: note that you need to search for `??` in the *output* of your document -- the log tells you what page(s) to look on.  searching in the input would be fruitless (and frustrating).