# Software to manage labelled objects for efficient cross-referencing (theorems, proofs, equationarrays, ...)

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, program

Is there perhaps open-source software for managing labelled objects?

I am looking for a BibDesk for theorems basically because I have rather many propositions and theorems floating around that I would like to reference. I am currently using an Excel spreadsheet to keep track of their labels, names but I am sure there must be some software, no?

Perhaps there exist general packages as well?

At the moment I am using TexShop which is an otherwise very good piece of software.

Thanks so much!

Comment: many tex editors keep track of all labels defined in a document so can offer context sensitive help on valid arguments to \ref, if that's the kind of information you mean, best to say which editor you use.

Comment: Try a simple document with a single `\label`, then as you type `\ref`, hit the F5 key (may need to hold down the Fn key, depending on the particular keyboard). Does that pop up a menu you can click in (or hit the down arrow) to select a particular label?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to but it sounds interesting @MikeRenfro

Comment: I'm referring to how autocomplete should work in TeXShop. via ([1](http://linguiacademic.blogspot.com/2014/02/texshop-autocomplete-in-mac.html), [2](http://danushkaresearch.blogspot.com/2010/06/texshop.html), and others). Please verify whether or not this works for you as well.

Comment: Oh yeah @MikeRenfro that does indeed work! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have switched to TexClipse because it's better at handling unwieldy documents but still it only picks up on the section labels in an overview fashion. It would be nice to see software that would compile a list of all theorems and equationarrays and so forth.

Comment: Please see my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128405/references-used-in-article/132150#132150. The first two possibilites are used while compiling your document, the third is a separat script you can run. Possible duplicate?

Comment: Bibliographic data doesn't depend on a particular document, whereas labels obviously do. The document itself is the source; with synchronization between source and PDF output, together with `hyperref`, it's really easy to navigate. Using a package such as those suggested by Kurt will help, too.