# Find unused bibkeys using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to get a list of bib-keys from my `.bib` file which I don't actually use in my document.

I have found "[Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries were not used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/unused-bibliography-entries-how-to-check-which-entries-were-not-used)" but since I'm using biblatex I don't have the information in the `.aux` files, so I can't use [checkcites](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites).

Is there a biblatex way to get such a list?

Comment: With `biber`, there is the option `--output_format=bibtex`, which will create a new `.bib` file of all the citations in the original `.tex` file.  Easy enough to do a diff (or what have you) after that.  Try: `latex myfile.tex && biber --output_format=bibtex myfile.bcf` which should create a file called `myfile_biber.bib`.

Comment: This sounds great, but my version of `biber` doesn't have this feature (`Unknown option: output_format`). Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8 of `biber`, which claims that several options names have changed.  I'd try `biber --help` to see if the option is available for your version under a different name.  Or just upgrade your `biblatex` and `biber` (you'd need to do both, however).

Comment: Alternatively, does this help you [How to split bibliography into “works cited” and “works not cited”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/35864)? To use this you would have to modify your document though, but these changes are only minute and can be easily undone.

Comment: @jon There is an option `--outformat=bbl|dot|bltxml`, so it looks like it doesn't support `.bib` at all. I'm on 0.9.9, so pretty old. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @moewe That's not what I *wanted*, but it's at least what I *need* :) Thanks!

Comment: It is easy enough to upgrade if you really want to.  Really.  Or simply use traditional `bibtex` + `bibtool` for the sake of constructing the new `.bib` (as long as you don't plan on doing this all the time).