# Ignore a bibliography field [e.g. "urldate"] for eliminating of biblatex/biber warnings

Tags: biblatex, warnings, biber

I have a large bibliography generated by a reference manager program (Citavi, but it can be anything else). The `urldate` field of all references is formatted as `urldate = {dd.mm.yyyy}`, which is not correct for `biblatex`. However, I don't want to change this field every time I update my HUGE bibliography from the reference manager app.
In fact, I receive no errors but many warnings like one below.

```
Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex) with 'XYZ.2003':
(biblatex) - Datamodel: Entry 'XYZ.2003' (bibliographie.bib)
: Invalid format '18.11.2013' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring.
```

I don't want to have these warning, since for many bibliography entries this type of warning will dominate and it will be hard to see the relevant warnings.

*I.e. these warnings need to be somehow suppressed*

For comleteness (partially using the example [Find unused bibkeys using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150701/find-unused-bibkeys-using-biblatex)),

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliograp.bib}
@BOOK{Ab_Steg,
author = "M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun",
title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
publisher = "Dover publications",
year = "1965",
urldate = {15.10.2013},
language="English" }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,twoside]{scrbook}  
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
        backend=biber,      
        date=short,
        firstinits=true,
    language=english]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{urldate}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{abstract}}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{bibliograp.bib}

\begin{document}
hello world \cite{Ab_Steg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As it can be seen, `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{urldate}}` doesn't prevent the warnings. I also expected that `language=german` (i.e. go away from the English date standard) in `biblatex` options could resolve the issue, but it also doesn't help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`biblatex` rightly warns you about a not well-formed field format, so the best solution is to do away with that and use the proper date format `yyyy-mm-dd`; since you use a citation manager that should be as easy as telling the citation manager to export the date properly (I have no idea how hard that actually is.).

Since you do not want to do this - and since you do not need the `urldate` field anyway, one solution is to just do away with the field `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}}`, but this of course still issues warnings, because, technically, `biber` is still processing the field (and still notices it is not well-formed). Note that you don't use `\clearfield{urldate}` here, because `biblatex` decomposes date fields into their year, month and day parts - it is enough to delete the year to suppress the output of the field.

To get rid of the errors, we need to prevent `biber` from seeing the bad field, so we just add

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

to our preamble. This will tell `biber` to discard the `urldate` field *without even properly looking at it*.

In my test run this MWE did not complain at all

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliograp.bib}
@BOOK{Ab_Steg,
author = "M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun",
title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
publisher = "Dover publications",
year = "1965",
urldate = {15.10.2013},
language="English" }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,twoside]{scrbook}  
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
        backend=biber,      
        date=short,
        firstinits=true,
    language=english]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{abstract}}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{bibliograp.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
hello world \cite{Ab_Steg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

One positive effect is that you can get rid of `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}` since that field is ignored further down the road (assuming we're travelling uphill here).

Comment: Moeve, you are right, it's possible to set up Citavi for Biblatex (and that's very easy, but unfortunately, the option doesn't lie on the surface).
So the best solution is really to try to tweak the reference manager app.

Comment: In addition to ``AtEveryBibitem``, I have found ``\AtEveryCitekey`` good to know about, e.g. to suppress the issue from the cite and get ``Author (date)`` rather than the less desirable ``Author (date, issue)``, you would do ``\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issue}}``.

Comment: @PatrickT The source mapping here is more radical than `\AtEveryBibitem` or `\AtEveryCitekey`. Note that `issue` is rarely the field you want, normally you are looking for `number`. It is a quirk of `biblatex-apa` that it shows the `issue` in the citation label, but apparently that is what the APA dictates.

Comment: Thanks moewe. I had both an issue ``number`` and an issue ``season``, e.g. Volume 1, Number 3, Fall 2018. I usually omit season, but if I do include it, the cite comes out as ``Author (2018, Spring).`` (I'll have to drop apa soon) I am using ``issue`` to store the season because of these remarks in the manual ''This field [issue] is intended for journals whose individual issues are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number.'' Also, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396421/best-way-to-encode-season-spring-summer-fall-winter-in-bibtex

Comment: @PatrickT In that case `issue` is OK. You could think about using `date` with `2018-23` instead, but I'm not sure what `biblatex-apa` makes of that.

Comment: Thanks! Probably time I try something other than ``apa``!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is possibly another way for ignoring the warnings; those come from a `\warn` command in the `.bbl` file:

```
$ sed -n '/\\warn/p' my_new_article.bbl 
      \warn{\item Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry 'author2001paper'}
      \warn{\item Overwriting field 'month' with month value from field 'date' for entry 'author2001paper'}
      \warn{\item Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry 'author2002paper'}
...
```

Clearly, if we get rid of these lines, we shouldn't be troubled by the warnings in Latex runs anymore; the above `sed` statement already prints confirming that our match regex is right; all we need to do is to `D`elete lines (to newline) and save an in-place replacement of the file:

```
sed -i '/\\warn/D' my_new_article.bbl
```

Then when I run `pdflatex my_new_article.tex`, I don't see those warnings anymore. Of course, this has to be done after each time you've ran `biber` or `bibtex` to re-generate the `.bbl` file (but it could pay off, if you tend to run `latex` more often than `bibtex`/`biber`)

Answer (score 0):

I got errors such as

> Overwriting field 'month' with month value from field 'date' for entry 'bibtexkey'
>
> Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry 'bibtexkey'

I silenced them using

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map[overwrite=true]{
   \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
   \step[fieldset=month, null]
   \step[fieldset=year, null]
  }
 }
}
```

In the preamble, but be aware this might remove month and year in your bibliography.

This answer uses info from a post before https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150723/110064