# bibtex - Change format of urldate

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, formatting, datetime

I have the problem that I use the citation manager Citavi and it can only export in the format `urldate = {dd.mm.yyyy}`. However Bibtex needs the format `urldate = {yyyy-mm-dd}`. It is not really realistic in my case to change all the dates of my bibliography manually, as I have many entries and after each export I would need to redo it.

For example my bibtex entry looks like this:

```
@Misc{FAO.2011,
  Title                    = {{FAOSTAT: Food balance sheet}},
  Author                   = {FAO},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Address                  = {Rome},
  Url                      = {http://faostat3.fao.org/download/FB/FBS/E},
  Urldate                  = {15.1.2014}
}
```

Then I receive following warning, when I compile it with BibTex

```
Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex) with 'FAO.2011':
(biblatex) - Datamodel: Entry 'FAO.2011' (literature.bib): Inval
id format '15.1.2014' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring.
```

Is there any way to change the format of Bibtex that it reads the `urldate` in format `urldate = {dd.mm.yyyy}` or can I convert it somehow to `urldate = {yyyy-mm-dd}`?

I have searched in the internet and haven't found any solution for this problem. It seems to be a specific problem of Citavi. To bad that Citavi is not customizable.

My question is similar to this: [Ignore a bibliography field [e.g. "urldate"] for eliminating of biblatex/biber warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150710/ignore-a-bibliography-field-e-g-urldate-for-eliminating-of-biblatex-biber-w). However, no solution was provided in this topic for my problem, because in this case `urldate` was not needed and thus just ignored. But I need to give `urldate`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Giacomo's feedback, I found another solution for this specific problem:

The problem is somehow more related to Citavi and Citavi is not as clear or transparent as LaTeX. For future reference of other people who might encounter a similar problem: Although Citavi asks to provide the date in the format `urldate={dd.mm.yyyy}` you can type it in as `urldate = {yyyy-mm-dd}`. The export does not make any problem. Strangly, by just changing one entry, all the other entries are exported accordingly. My fault not trying it out earlier. I should have tried it out earlier.

Comment: You could also use sed (stream editor), to edit the files.

Comment: Is there a setting option in citavi to change the date format in general?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `biblatex` package you can use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=urldate,
            match=\regexp{([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})},
            replace={$3-$2-$1},
            final]
        }
    }
}
```

in your preamble to reformat `urldate` field of input `*.bib` files.

Comment: an example of the output for this would be pretty helpful

Comment: The code seems not working

Answer (score 1):

for forcing the formatting in BibTeX, I use the double braces, e.g.:

```
Urldate  = {{15/01/2014}}
```

Comment: This seems not idiomatic and has to be done for every single bibliography entry.

Comment: With `biblatex` (which the question is about) this won't work. Input in date fields must be given in ISO 8601 format. Input that cannot be parsed as ISO 8601 is ignored. If I try the input I get `Entry '<entrykey>' (<file name>): Invalid format '{15/01/2014}' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring` and no `urldate` output whatsoever.

Comment: This *migtht* work for BibTeX styles that support a `urldate` field. But I don't think there are a lot of those (if any).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, and because I just stumbled upon this:
Citavi 6 includes a setting for this, found under `Options - Formatting`.

It will then use the chosen format for new entries, and when you insert the current date through the context menu. Existing dates are NOT updated.

[image: screenshot of options dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little python script that changes the format of urldate:
place your .bib file in the same directory than this script and name it "quellen.bib" and run the script. A new formated file named "changedFile.bib" will appear

```
import re

file = open("quellen.bib","r");
fileChanged = open("changedFile.bib","w");
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})");

for line in file:
    if "urldate =" in line and pattern.search(line):
        #save end of line to add it later to the modified date
        endline = line[line.index('}')+1:len(line)];
        date = line[line.index('{')+1:line.index('}')];
        month = int(date[0:date.index('/')]);
        date = date[date.index('/')+1:len(date)];
        day = int(date[0:date.index('/')]);
        date = date[date.index('/')+1:len(date)];
        year = int(date);
        if month > 12:
            # check if month and day are reversed
            temp = day;
            day = month;
            month = temp;
        # check if every value is ledgit
        if(month > 0 and month < 13 and day >0 and day < 32 and year > 1000):
            if(month<10):
                #add 0 if month or day is less then 10
                month = "0"+str(month);
            if(day<10):
                day = "0"+str(day);    
            fileChanged.write(" urldate = {"+ str(year)+"-"+str(month)+"-"+str(day)+"}"+endline);
        else:
            print("something is wrong with this line: ");
            print("day: ",day,"montH: ",month, "year: ",year);
            print(line);
    else:
        fileChanged.write(line);
file.close;
fileChanged.close;
```