# Numbered bibliography style with urldate support

Tags: biblatex

does someone know a bibliography style which supports the `urldate` (and prints it, e.g., as "last access ...") and prints the citations with numbers in square brackets ([1], [2], ...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the default with `biblatex`.

Comment: That poses very little restrictions on the style you want to use. You have tagged your question with `biblatex`. Are you actually looking for a `biblatex` style (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or for a BibTeX style (`\bibliographystyle` etc.)? `biblatex` and traditional BibTeX are incompatible, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. So the distinction is crucial. But the `biblatex` standard style `numeric` should be able to do to satisfy the two demands currently listed in the question out of the box.

Comment: I literally spend the whole day on this (including some memory errors), citavi exported my dates as MM/DD/YYYY while biblatex requires "YYYY-MM-DD". Now it works... thanks guys

Comment: OK, so this is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429297/35864 (if you replace `.` by `/` and `$3-$2-$1` by `$3-$1-$2`)? Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229073/35864