# Best way to encode season (spring, summer, fall, winter) in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I have an article that was published in "Summer 1972". What's the best way of including this information in a BibTeX entry? A literal

```
year = {Summer 1972}
```

probably isn't recommended since `Summer` won't get translated to other languages.

As a side note, "summer" probably isn't an accurate specification of time. Anyone from Australia will confirm this.

Comment: 1972 is as good as Summer 1972 I think.

Comment: If the article identifies itself as being published in "Summer 1972", I would tend to retain the language of the article.

Comment: For `bibtex` I would use `month={Summer}` (this won't translate). But better with `biblatex` and use `issue={\bibstring{summer}}` if you want the string to be translated.

Answer (score 11):

```
year = {Summer 1972}
```

Is not recommended. Not only because it will not be translated, but also because it can seriously mess with sorting if you happen to sort by year. Ideally the `year` field should only contain an integer in 'year range'; this is definitely the case with `biblatex`, where you get complaints otherwise.

With BibTeX (`.bst` styles) you could use

```
month = {Summer}
```

This would still not be translated automatically, it is also not technically correct and some styles might expect the `month` to be a number and fail.

With `biblatex`, for example, `month = {Summer}` is not good enough since `biblatex` expects the `month` to be a number.
If the work you refer to was published in the Summer issue of a journal you could use

```
issue = {Summer}
```

or even `issue = {\bibstring{summer}}` (only with newer versions) with `biblatex`. But `issue` is largely ignored for entries that are not `@article`s, so it might not be appropriate here.

`biblatex` gives you another way to specify the summer 1972 as the date. With ISO 8601 (Part 2, Level 1) features (https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-2.pdf) you can specify the season in the date field (https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-2.pdf, §4.7.1)

> For  a  year-and-month  expression  (e.g.  1984-04)  the  month  component  may take on values of 21 or above (in place of a month  value, 01 through 12).   [...] The values 21, 22, 23, 24 may be used to signify 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter', respectively.

So you could say

```
date = {1972-22}
```

for you example.

I'll leave it to you to decide whether or not specifying the 'Summer' makes sense. You rightly point out that summer is a location dependent term. Your reader will generally not gain a lot of insights if you specify 'Summer 1972' instead of '1972' (expect if the exact date is important, or you need to establish precedence, but then 'summer' might be too vague).

Comment: I think the point is that specifying the season helps locate the article if it is published in a journal which labels its issues by season rather than using numbers. It's also important for encyclopaedia entries which are specified by season. In many cases, omitting the season leaves the reference information incomplete. (So I take it the season will refer to the season where the journal or encyclopaedia is published/edited.)

Answer (score 3):

BibTeX is not really multilingual, so the best approximation is to define a string:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@string{summer="Summer"}

@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  month=summer,
  year=2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]