# Encoding of quarter into date with ISO 8601 does not work in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, date

I'm trying to encode an article that was published in the first quarter of 2004. Following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396421/396619), I'm using the ISO 8601 feature of the `date` field with BibLaTeX, special numbers are defined for divisions of the year as specified in the [documentation](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0039_iso_wd_8601-2_2016-02-16.pdf). But it is not accepted, the log saying : `Invalid format '2004-33' of date field 'date' - ignoring.`

Here is the output:

[image: result with quarter]

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{GauthierParticipation,
        author = {Guy Gauthier},
        date = {2004-33},
        issuetitle = {Le cinéma militant reprend le travail},
        journal = {CinémAction},
        number = {110},
        pages = {59-65},
        title = {Cinéma, vidéo, militantisme et participation (1968-1975)}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Curiously, when I'm trying with a seasonal range, eg `2004-21` for Spring 2004, it works fine:

[image: result with season]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As far as I can see from the biblatex docs it is using `ISO 8601-2` I'm not sure that `2004-33` is even allowed, and 33 (if that is referring to a week number is certainly not in the first quarter.

Comment: Actually, the doc linked in the post specifies that extra-month numbers can be used: 21-24 for Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter, independent of “Hemisphere”; 25-28 for Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter in Northern Hemisphere; 29-32 for Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter in Southern Hemisphere; 33-36 for Quarter 1, Quarter 2, Quarter 3, Quarter 4 (3 months each), 37-39 for Quadrimester 1, Quadrimester 2, Quadrimester 3 (4 months each) and 40-41 for Semestral 1, Semestral-2 (6 months each)

Comment: Can you refer me to where?

Comment: It's here on page 7: https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0039_iso_wd_8601-2_2016-02-16.pdf

Comment: I'm referring to the biblatex manual not an ISO standards page.

Comment: should it be ```2004-W33```.

Comment: Actually, the manual at page 41 only speaks of seasons, not more… It seems that not the whole feature have been implemented… https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: As far as I can see from table 4 in the biblatex manual `2004-33` is not allowed `33` should be a month number

Comment: @Oni did you try that? It fails at my end

Comment: The term `week` does not even exist in the biblatex manual

Comment: @daleif I mean form to mark ```ISO``` week number.

Comment: @Oni it still have to be supported by `biblatex` which it is not, see the log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to ISO 8601:2019, so I can't be sure what exactly the standard says on this, but `biblatex`'s date format was originally written based on EDTF (https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/). Specifically `biblatex` implements EDTF Level 1 (or its ISO 8601 equivalent, which should be ISO 8601-2 Clause 4, level 1).

As far as I can see level 1 only supports the seasons as (non-month) sub-year groupings (https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/)

> The values `21`, `22`, `23`, `24` may be used used to signify ' Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter', respectively, in place of a month value (`01` through `12`) for a year-and-month format string.

Extended sub-year groupings are available in level 2, but that is indeed not supported by `biblatex`.

I'm afraid `2004-33` won't work for that reason.