# Putting the season in the date of a journal in the reference list

Tags: biber, apa7

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{Smi23,
author={John Smith},
title={Article Title},
date={2023-23},%month 23 is autumn
journal={Journal Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Smi23}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I run pdfLaTeX, Biber, then pdfLaTeX again and get the following output:

[image: Reference list shows the year only]

I want only the year to be shown in the text, but the year and the season to be shown in the reference list. What do I need to do to get the following output?

[image: Reference list shows year and season]

Comment: how are you defining seasons? (I've never seen such a date format in a bibliography!!) If you specify exact season dates I'm sure someone could code it in biblatex.  month 23??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's in ISO 8601. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396619/64175).

Comment: If you look at the .bbl file created by my .tex file here, you will see the lines `\field{year}{2023}` and `\field{yeardivision}{autumn}` so that means month 23 is indeed interpreted as autumn.

Comment: Wow, truely weird. but if moewe says it works in biblatex, I'm sure it does.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've never seen it formatted quite like this, but it is common to see season specified in bibliography entries. In many cases, it is essential and omitting it leaves the reference incomplete. (That is, a reader cannot easily locate the item without the season information.) Season is defined however the source defines it. If an encyclopaedia article is part of the "Spring 2001" edition, it's spring; if a journal has "Autumn 2022" on the cover, it's autumn. What the ISO format means I'm less sure as it omits possibilities such as "Fall" and "Autumn/Winter" which are also common.

Comment: I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydX8o.png. Which version of `biblatex-apa` are you using? (Add `\listfiles` to your `.tex` file and check the package versions at the end of the `.log` file.)

Comment: @moewe Many files (no biblatex-apa), the relevant ones seem to be biblatex.sty 2022/02/02 v3.17, apa.dbx 2021/12/24 v9.15, blx-compat.def 2022/02/02 v3.17, biblatex.def 2022/02/02 v3.17, standard.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17, apa.bbx 2021/12/24 v9.15, apa.cbx 2021/12/24 v9.15, blx-case-expl3.sty 2022/02/02 v3.17, english.lbx 2022/02/02 v3.17, american.lbx 2022/02/02 v3.17, american-apa.lbx 2021/12/24 v9.15, english-apa.lbx 2021/12/24 v9.15.

Comment: It seems that I have biblatex-apa 2022-01-03 (9.15) installed.

Comment: @moewe, I've updated my miktex so that my biblatex-apa is dated April 7, 2023. It works correctly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using an old version of `biblatex-apa` (January 3, 2022). I updated to the latest version (April 7, 2023) and it now works as I wanted it. I thank user moewe for his comment that led to the solution to my problem.