# Know which entry of bib file has not been used

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way of knowing if I left out any bibliography entry in a specific tex file from an specific bib file?

I am doing a kind of a literature review and every day I write a bit I find several papers to add. I generally add them and write about them in the moment, but it would be nice to make sure I haven't left any of them out.

Comment: use grep or some other search tool, or use a number in order of reference bibligraphy style and put `\nocite{*}` at the end of the document then any "unused" references will appear at the end of your reference list with the highest numbers, coming after any real references

Comment: if you include a bibliography, and use either `\cite` or `\nocite` for each of the items you're writing about, after processing the review with bibliography, your log will tell you what's missing.  if you've used `\cite`, there will be `??` in your output instead of the cited item, but only the log will say what the reference label is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Definetly the answer I was looking for. I didn't thought it ws going to be as easy. I believe you should answer the question, for the shake of knowledge base philosophy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `grep` or some other search tool, or use a number in order of reference bibliography style and put `\nocite{*}` at the end of the document then any "unused" references will appear at the end of your reference list with the highest numbers, coming after any real reference

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `checkcites` script, which is available in every recent TeX distribution.

Here's an example file, save it as `checktest.tex`; usage of `\jobname` and `filecontents*` is just for making the example selfcontained, you'll use your own `.bib` file, of course.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{used,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2015},
}
@article{unused,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{used}

\cite{undefined}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

If you compile it and run

```
checkcites checktest
```

The terminal will output

```
checkcites.lua -- a reference checker script (v1.0i)
Copyright (c) 2012 Enrico Gregorio, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda

I found 2 citation(s).
Great, there's only one 'bib' file. Let me check it.
I found 2 reference(s).

Unused reference(s) in your bibliography file(s): 1
- unused

Undefined reference(s) in your TeX file: 1
- undefined
```

So the `unused` entry has no corresponding `\cite` command in the file, while `undefined` has a `\cite`, but has no entry in the `.bib` file.

Comment: This answer is awesome