# Printing the bibliographic entries in a bib file that are not cited in the document

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using a `bibtex` to manage my references in LaTeX by `cite` package. The normal behavior of this package is printing a bibliography of all cited references in the document, however, I want its complement. In other words, suppose that I have cited two references, but want the bibliography contain the third one, which I have not cited.

**Question: How to print just all the entries of a bibliography file which are not cited?**

For the application, I check manually to see which references are not cited in my document which is a boring workaround!

As a minimal working example for test, suppose that my bibliography file is `biblio.bib` with the following contents:

```
    @ARTICLE{Grzymala-Busse_1997_Classification,
      author = {Grzymala-Busse, Jerzy W.},
      title = {Classification of Unseen Examples under Uncertainty},
      journal = {Fundamenta Informaticae},
      year = {1997},
      volume = {30},
      pages = {255--267},
      number = {3},
      month = jan
    }
    @INCOLLECTION{Skowron_2005_Approximation,
      author = {Skowron, Andrzej and Åwiniarski, Roman and Synak, Piotr},
      title = {Approximation Spaces and Information Granulation},
      booktitle = {Transactions on Rough Sets {III}},
      publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
      year = {2005},
      editor = {Peters, James F. and Skowron, Andrzej},
      number = {3400},
      series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
      pages = {175--189},
      month = jan
    }
    @INCOLLECTION{Yao_2012_Outline,
      author = {Yao, Yiyu},
      title = {An Outline of a Theory of Three-Way Decisions},
      booktitle = {Rough Sets and Current Trends in Computing},
      publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
      year = {2012},
      editor = {Yao, JingTao and Yang, Yan and SÅowiÅski, Roman and Greco, Salvatore
        and Li, Huaxiong and Mitra, Sushmita and Polkowski, Lech},
      pages = {1--17},
      month = jan
    }
```

and a LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Grzymala-Busse_1997_Classification,Yao_2012_Outline}

    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With biblatex + biber it would be easy. I don't know a way with bibtex, but you could use the backref package + `\nocite{*}. Then would would as least see which entries have not been cited.

Comment: I did not know `biblatex` and `biber`, however the second solution seems good. I'll check it. Would you mind provide your solution with `biblatex` and `biber`? Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited

Comment: Thanks. That's a great solution, unless most journals do not support biblatex. However, I wonder if there are any solutions with `bibtex`, so I'll wait for an answer.

Comment: Related: [Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries were not used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43288)

Comment: The bibtopic package seems to have code. There is even an example with `\btPrintNotCited`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. was faster :) additionally related (more concise): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224391

Comment: @Harald Yes, was going to add a link to that one as well.